# How to delay the execution of a function with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have that kind of code to append an `li` element to a given `ul` with a fancy effect, then I call a function whose behavior depends on the # of children of that `ul` :

```
$(li).hide().appendTo("#ul-authors").show("blind");
toggleIfNeeded();

...

function toggleIfNeeded() {
  if ($("#ul-authors > li").length === 1) {
     doSomething();
  } else {
     doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

The problem is, when `toggleIfNeeded` is called, the new `li` does not seem to exist yet, since the effect is not totally performed. If I remove the effect, it works correctly.

How can I do that ? I guess I need some sort of a timer, but that would be asynchronous (I don't want to block the app for a fancy effect) or, even better, a way to tell "call that function when the effect is performed".

I don't have the possibility to change `1` with `0` in the above since the code can be called in other contexts where no effect is involved.

Comment: do `.show("blind", toggleIfNeeded)`

Comment: Well, thanks @XuqiciAcerto, but my question was more precisely "how do we use callbacks in that context ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `.show()`. If you change

```
$(li).hide().appendTo("#ul-authors").show("blind");
toggleIfNeeded();
```

to

```
$(li).hide().appendTo("#ul-authors").show("blind", toggleIfNeeded);
```

then your function will be called automatically when the animation is finished.

Answer (score 1):

the second parameter to show() can be a function where you can do what you want when animation ends

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.show('<effect>', callbackFunction)
```